# Python + Selenium, how to follow redirect page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am working with Selenium WebDriver. An example, http://racernet.murraystate.edu/phone/.

I key in a name in the “Name” field and click the “Search” button.

Here is what I have so far:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get("http://racernet.murraystate.edu/phone/")
driver.find_element_by_name("mysearch").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("mysearch").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("mysearch").send_keys("johnny")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

however the webpage turns to another to show the searched results.

How can I have selenium.webdriver automatically following the page turned to (especially in circumstances the redirected pages are variable)?

Comment: you would need to use switch_to_window(handle) to switch to a new window

Comment: IDK, but you might be hitting this bug https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389

Comment: I didnt see any redirection after search. Did you mean clicking google doc link "Click here to request an update to your"?  It is redirecting and Phantomjs cant handle it.

Comment: @Mesut Güneş, after Search button clicked, the page address is changed to: http://racernet.murraystate.edu/phone/index2.cfm.

Comment: What do you want*? In my suite, Phantomjs still handles the page: `driver.current_url >>>
u'http://racernet.murraystate.edu/phone/index2.cfm'` and `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.bodyText > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1)").text >>>
u'Simon, Johnny C Lecturer\nEducation and Human Services'`

Comment: @@Mesut Güneş, would you mind giving the full lines in an answer below? thanks.